# Identify the web site loaded in web view iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, websites, url

I have an iPhone application that just shows a web page when you use it. I don't know the URL of the site it loads. Is there any way I can get the URL of the page the application loads?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not directly related to the iPhone or iOS but is about sniffing the network (and/or jailbreaking the device) to know which website is being accessed.

Answer (score 4):

To determine the web site, you will need to intercept the network traffic travelling between your iPhone and your Internet Service Provider (ISP).

To do this you need to set your phone to use WiFi and to pass network traffic through a proxy. Proxies include [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org) and [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com).

A good proxy will offer log files and allow you to see server addresses and, if not encrypted, requested URLs.

Alternatively, you could contact the application developer and ask.

Answer (score 1):

No, You can't get the URL of the loaded page until the developer of that application intended to show the url.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to intercept the traffic apart from a proxy is to set up a sniffer, such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Here are some instructions from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13874035/2871638).

If you prefer to use command line tools you could also use [tcpdump](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tcpdump.1.html), which is available from the OS X command line.

Another good proxy which I used to use in my work is paros, but it has now been superseeded by [ZED attack proxy from OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project).

Comment: Is it possible to intercept the traffic between the iPhone and the network this way?

Comment: Hi @GrahamMiln yes it should be given the link I provided from [stackexchange](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13874035/2871638).

Comment: Thanks, I see the iPhone still needs to be switched to WiFi for this to work. That makes sense for me now.